# Update different sheets automatically when Google Form Response sheet updates

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have a Google form which is linked to a sheet **Form Response 1**. Now I have different sheets (around 10 sheets) which I want to populate automatically when the **Form Response 1** receives any response.

In **Form Response 1** sheet, I have column "Name". Now I want to gather data in different sheets with respect to "Name". Can someone post me the formula of how every sheet updates its data when **Form Response 1** updates any record.

Comment: ok, and? what's you question?

Comment: it sounds like a FILTER or QUERY formula on each of the 10 sheets would do the job

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I have mentioned my question " I want to populate automatically when the Form Response 1 receives any response."

Comment: @ChrisHick I am updating my question which may help you to answer it

Comment: Populate with what? What have you tried already?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I have updated my questions. I have a sheet **Form Response 1**. I want to collect data/row from this sheet and populate in some separate sheet. I want to automate this and don't want to do it again and again. I want to enter the formula at once and let the sheet update every time when a records enters in **Form Response 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Name is column B you could try one of these two formulae:

`=FILTER('Form responses 1'!A2:Z,'Form responses 1'!B2:B="Name")`

`=QUERY('Form responses 1'!A2:Z,"where B='Name'")`

Then amend the 'Name' to whichever value you want to appear on each sheet

Comment: Will this work automatically whenever any new row will be added in the **Form Response 1**

Aslo, will the FILTER not check only A2 cell?

Comment: It will check the whole range from cell A2 to column Z.  It includes all rows so will pick up as new ones are added.  Try it out on your sheet and see if it works.  If not, please add a link to some sample data.

Comment: Where do I need to write this FILTER and QUERY? Will this automatically work when my **Form Response 1** updates. Or I  need to put this Filter+Query every time I want to update my sheet?

Comment: you can use either a FILTER or a QUERY as they both have the same output. I'm assuming you have a separate tab for each 'Name' value so enter the formula into cell A1 on each sheet and change the formula to whichever 'Name' is relevant to that sheet.  The formula will automatically pull through new submissions as the Form Response sheet updates.

Comment: Thanks, let me try that